# Nmap not showing MAC address & does not seem to be doing ARP ping scans

Tags: nmap, parrot-os

I am following a course online, in the course an Nmap scan is undertaken with the following results:
[image]. As you can see, the second from bottom line is `MAC Address: DE:AD:00:00:BE:EF` and the SENT and RCVD lines show an ARP request and an ARP reply.

However, when I do this I do not see the MAC Address, nor do I see the ARP lines. I see instead am ICMP response, here is a screenshot from my result:

[image]

I am doing the nmap with sudo privileges so I'm not sure why I am not seeing the MAC address.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nmap 192.168.43.109 -sn -oA host -PE --reason` This command will only show the MAC address if your machine and the target machine are on the same network.